# Covariance for Two Variables when Divided by a Third Variable

Tags: covariance

In a [Bioinformatics article](http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/30/15/2155.full) appendix, I found the equation :

$$
Cov(X/Z, Y/Z) = Cov(X, Y)E(1/Z^2) + E(X)E(Y)Var(1/Z)
$$

when supposing that the random vector $(X, Y)$ with covariance $Cov(X, Y)$ is independent of the random variable $Z$. $X$ and $Y$ are not correlated. What are the steps to arrive at that expansion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Cov(X/Z, Y/Z)=E(\frac{XY}{Z^2})-E(\frac{X}{Z})E(\frac{Y}{Z}).$ The independence of the random vector $(X,Y)$ of $Z$ implies that the vector is also independent of $\frac{1}{Z}$. Then $=E(\frac{XY}{Z^2})-E(\frac{X}{Z})E(\frac{Y}{Z})=E(XY)E(\frac{1}{Z^2})-E(X)E(Y)E(\frac{1}{Z})^2$.

We can add and substract the same element without changing the expression:

$=E(XY)E(\frac{1}{Z^2})- [E(X)E(Y)E(\frac{1}{Z^2})-E(X)E(Y)E(\frac{1}{Z^2})] -E(X)E(Y)E(\frac{1}{Z})^2=$
$=E(\frac{1}{Z^2})[E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)] + E(X)E(Y)[E(\frac{1}{Z^2}) - E(\frac{1}{Z})^2]=$
$=E(\frac{1}{Z^2})Cov(X,Y) + E(X)E(Y)Var(\frac{1}{Z})$.